# Page not found error on redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have the following code in the head tag of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startime = (new Date()).getTime();

window.onload = function()
{
    record_visit('ol');         
    setInterval("record_visit('update')", 300000);
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(){ record_visit('obul'); } //obul = onbeforeunload

function record_visit(value) {
    var x = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
var url='<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>';
x.open("GET", "/sc/count_visit.php?t=" + (((new Date()).getTime() - startime) / 1000)+"&type="+value+"&url="+url, false);
    x.send(null);
}
```

It works great but on my drupal site under recent log messages I received an error:

```
page not found  02/27/2012 - 23:04  count_visit.php Anonymous (not verified)
```

Since I have around 6k visitors a day that error appears many times in just a minute.

Am I missing something on the code above? I believe it's not count_visit.php that has problem.

Comment: Please do not pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: thanks for the comments. But I cannot get your point. I am fairly new to javascript and willing to understand if you can give me some modified code above.

Comment: Simply replace your setInterval line with this: `setInterval(function() { record_visit('update'); }, 300000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to url encode your `url` variable. `encodeURIComponent(url)`

Comment: it seems that the error still continues. but i have to wait for few more hours. may be it's just a cache w/ the page that don't have encodeURIComponent as of now.